# Extract timestamp from FM1100 record

Tags: php, avl-tree

I am trying to decode some data from a FM1100 teltonika record such as this :

> 080400000113fc208dff000f14f650209cca80006f00d60400040004030101150316030001460000015d0000000113fc17610b000f14ffe0209cc580006e00c00500010004030101150316010001460000015e0000000113fc284945000f150f00209cd200009501080400000004030101150016030001460000015d0000000113fc267c5b000f150a50209cccc0009300680400000004030101150016030001460000015b0004

In the above example I actually just want to extract the timestamp of the log. This timestamp is the string "00000113fc208dff".

How can I transform this string to a timestamp?

Comment: Can you give us more details about the format of the record and/or the timestamp?

Comment: In fact, I can give you the doc where I get this exemple [http://sourceforge.net/p/opengts/discussion/579834/thread/6fd0ffe8/6213/attachment/FMXXXX%20Protocols%20v2.10.pdf](here). But I can't do more, sorry, I'm really lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the protocol documentation I've [found here](http://sourceforge.net/p/opengts/discussion/579834/thread/6fd0ffe8/6213/attachment/FMXXXX%20Protocols%20v2.10.pdf) this record actually contains multiple log entries (pg. 5) each of which has its own timestamp.

Assuming you just need the timestamp of the first log entry you can extract it like this (fiddle [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad4f727d14a6666bfcbaaa4ef753ba94c0facab3)):

```
$input = '080400000113fc208dff000f14f650209cca80006f00d60400040004030101150316030001460000015d0000000113fc17610b000f14ffe0209cc580006e00c00500010004030101150316010001460000015e0000000113fc284945000f150f00209cd200009501080400000004030101150016030001460000015d0000000113fc267c5b000f150a50209cccc0009300680400000004030101150016030001460000015b0004';

$data = unpack('A2/A2/A16timestamp', $input);
$timestamp = hexdec($data['timestamp']);

echo $timestamp . PHP_EOL;
```

If you need to read the timestamps of each log record you will need parse the IO element data for each one because it is variable in length.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was completely lost, I assumed it was hexa but can't found th way to transform it to int. I tried everything except hexdec!